# Need to append the data for 3 files in bash

Tags: awk, sed

**File1 input data(has only single value):**-

```
20230118
```

**File2 input data:-**

```
USD,1823
BXX,200
CDD,500
XR,89078
```

**File 3 input data(has only single value):-**

```
15678
```

***output data:-***

```
20230118,USD,180,15678
20230118,BXX,200,15678
20230118,CDD,500,15678
```

I have tried awk and sed commands

Comment: Please, check [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75162722/edit) to remember how to format your code for next times. I do it for you.

Comment: please update the question to include your `awk` and `sed` attempts along with the (wrong) output generated by your `awk/sed` code

Comment: [edit] your question to explain why that would be the expected output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

### Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
$ cat 15678.txt
15678

$ cat 20230118.txt
20230118

$ cat file.txt
USD,1823
BXX,200
CDD,500
XR,89078
```

```
prefix=$(< 20230118.txt) suffix=$(< 15678.txt)
while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$prefix,$line,$suffix"; done < file.txt
```

### Output

```
20230118,USD,1823,15678
20230118,BXX,200,15678
20230118,CDD,500,15678
20230118,XR,89078,15678
```

Comment: Very nice! ...  it may help O.P. script a solution to add `prefix=$(<file1);suffix-$(<file3)`. If there are line endings then use `${suffix%?}` etc in the `echo` line. (You may even need 2 `??`) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1&&++f<3 {                       # read 2 first files
           a[f]=$0                           # hash pre and suf to a
           next                              # moving on to next file as only one line per file
       }
       {                                     # 3rd file (maybe f==3 just in case)
           printf "%s,%s,%s\n",a[1],$0,a[2]  # output
       }'  file1 file3 file2                 # mind the file order
```

Output:

```
20230118,USD,1823,15678
20230118,BXX,200,15678
20230118,CDD,500,15678
20230118,XR,89078,15678
```

Answer (score 0):

with `join`

```
$ join -t, -j9 <(join -t, -j9 file1 file2) file3 | cut -d, -f3-

20230118,USD,1823,15678
20230118,BXX,200,15678
20230118,CDD,500,15678
20230118,XR,89078,15678
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
yes "$(paste file1 file3)" | sed 'R /dev/stdin' file2 | sed -E 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)\t/\2,\1,/'
```

Use paste to create an infinite file of file1 and file3.

Pipe the above contents into sed and append each line to each line of file2.

Pipe the above into another sed that fetches two lines at a time and formats as required.

Alternative using GNU parallel:

```
parallel -k echo "{1},{2},{3}" :::: file1 :::: file2 :::: file3
```